# See all the parameters of the request erlang/ChicagoBoss

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I'm getting `undefined` everytime from the response for a hidden field  "F_02_displayorder". I'm debugging value as in Erlang Code:

```
error_logger:info_msg(" Value - F_02_displayorder ", [Req:post_param("F_02_displayorder")])
```

You would know that `Air Client` doesn't have any javascript debugger. So, I'm not able to see what values are going in the `request`. but now I want to check what values are coming in the `Request`. 
Can anyone tell me what should I do to check all the values in the dictionary.

In python I was creating a request dictionary like `dict(zip(request.POST.keys(), request.POST.values()))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Req:request_body()` I think this is what you're looking for. This returns a binary string you might need to split it by "&" and "=" to get exact values. Here is the way you can split it.

```
   RequestBody = string:tokens(binary_to_list(Req:request_body()), "&")
```